# HTML CSS min-width fluid width

Tags: html, css, fluid-layout

Is there anyway I can style my CSS to make my jsfiddle example contain a fluid width?

http://jsfiddle.net/x2qk7/99/

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$('a.next').click(function(){  
    $('.slide').animate({"left": "-=480"}, 500);
})
$('a.back').click(function(){  
    $('.slide').animate({"left": "+=480"}, 500);
})

});​

.form-slides {width:480px; overflow:hidden; border: 1px solid #ccc;}
.wrap { width: 9999px; }
.slide {width:480px; float:left; position: relative; background:#eee;}
.next {float:right;}

<div class="form-slides">
<div class="wrap">

    <div class="slide">
        <p>Lipsum blah blah blah</p>
        <a href="#" class="next">Next</a> 
    </div>
    <div class="slide">
        <p>Lipsum blah blah blah</p>
        <a href="#" class="next">Next</a> 
        <a href="#" class="back">back</a> 
    </div>
    <div class="slide">
        <p>Lipsum blah blah blah</p>
        <a href="#" class="back">back</a> 
    </div>

</div>
```

​

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Replace `width:480px` with `width: 100%`, and move the border declaration to the `.wrap` div:

```
.form-slides { width:100%; }
.wrap { border: 1px solid #ccc; }
.slide { width:100%; float:left; background:#eee; }
.next { float:right; }
```

Comment: Can you provide a jfiddle example?

Comment: I need the next and prev to be fluid and they aren't.  Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Container is Fluid width.
Slides are 100% of parent width.
Animations are -(slideId * 100)%
See example here: http://psofe.com/mhealth/

Example has a slideshow with fluid width (using this method), and maximum width.